# Raster calculator reclass 0 as 0 QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, reclassify

I want to process a raster with values 0-16. I want to set all values between 1 and 15 as 1, a value of 16 as 0 and cells with a value of 0 as 0.

How do I maintain a cell value of 0?

I have tried the following:

```
("raster_name@1" !=0 AND "raster_name@1" <= 15*1)+("raster_name@1" = 16*0)
```

Results in: Values of 16 as 0, values 1-15 as 1, values 0 also = 1

I also tried:

```
("raster_name@1" !=0 AND "raster_name@1" <= 15*1)+("raster_name@1" 16*0)+("raster_name@1" = 0*0)
```

Results in: Values of 16 as 0, values 1-15 as 1, values 0 = 2

Please, can you explain how to retain cells with a 0 value as 0?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS.SE. Have you simply tried `"raster_name@1" !=0 AND "raster_name@1" <= 15`?

Comment: What ArMoraer proposes, works. I added some - maybe unnecessary - stuff and came up with ("raster_name@1" != 0 AND "raster_name@1" < 16) = 1 AND ("raster_name@1" = 0 AND "raster_name@1" > 15) = 0

Comment: @ArMoraer, the simple one works, I was over complicating it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply write `"raster_name@1" != 0 AND "raster_name@1" <= 15` in order to set all values between 1 and 15 to 1, and everything else to 0.

Comment: One could also `>= 1` or `> 0`.