# Make rasters to show the extent of certain data values

Tags: qgis, raster, analysis

I'm trying make a raster of the area between 5 and 10 thousand feet in Colorado. I have DEMs, and I'd like to make a raster where all the area in this range is a value of 1, and the area outside the range (<5000 or >10,000) is 0. I tried (lower value < "raster-name" < upper value) in raster calculator, but this did not work (it made files with no data- I have a post about this too, but at this point I think it'd be more helpful to just start over and try a different way)

How should I approach this? And if there's a way I can avoid analyzing the ~60 DEMs one at a time, that would be even better

This isn't answered by a [similar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274586/raster-calculator-reclass-0-as-0-qgis) post because they wanted one 'less than' bound and a 'does not equal a value' (they wanted less than or equal to 15 and doesn't equal 0). I'm looking for something that works with an upper AND a lower bound

Comment: You could use the reclassify tool available in GRASS.  See this link:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I think this is what I want

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial or comprehensive guide to r.rclass anywhere? The GRASS help is pretty vague and glosses over the things I don't understand (how specifically to create the rules file, and the specifics of selecting the input file). The online tutorials say you can enter the rules right into the r.reclass dialog, which in my version I cannot, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Or would it be better to ask this in a separate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster calculator (from menu `Raster | Raster calculator`) is a good tool. The expression to extract elevation between 5,000 and 10,000 ft is:

```
("YourRaster@1" >= 5000) AND ("YourRaster@1" <= 10000)
```

It will look like below:

[image]

---

*Additional note: - not mandatory*

After conversion (to `0` and `1`), you may want to change the bit depth of your raster to integer (since the default output of Raster Calculator is 32-bit float value).

In the processing toolbox, you have a SAGA `Change data storage` tool to convert raster bit depth.

[image]

`Unsigned 1 byte integer` will give you a raster with 1-byte (8-bit) integer (0, 1) value.